# QSqlTableModel, QTableView change columns not updated

Tags: qt

I have a SQL model that connects to a single table, this table will change the number of columns depending on certain conditions during the execution of the program. The model is connected to a QTableView.
I have a function that controls the number of columns at the end of the function i have a call to model->select(), to update the information of the model and tableView->reset(), to what i thought would rearrange the view adding or taking away columns.
The problem is that the view does not change from the original number of columns that it had. If i reduce the number i can see that the data change and show empty on the missing columns. Is there a command for the tableView to resize it self?
Editing the question
in the constructor of the class i'm reading the table and setting it to the view:

```
  header = new QSqlTableModel(parent,data->m_db);
  header->setTable("C"+QString::number(markTime.toSecsSinceEpoch())+"T");
  header->select();
  ui->heading->setModel(header);
  ui->heading->show();
```

Every time that that the number of columns is changed is an SQL procedure to change the number of columns:

```
void ImportProcess::copyTable(QString oldTable, QString newTable)
{
  QSqlQuery queryOld, queryNew;
  queryOld.prepare("select * from :oldTable");
  queryOld.bindValue(":oldTable",oldTable);
  queryOld.exec();

  if(queryOld.record().isEmpty()==true) return; //Old table was empty, nothing to copy

  int oldColumn=queryOld.record().count();

  QString replaceLine="insert into "+newTable+" values(";
  while(queryOld.next()==true)
    {
      replaceLine.append(QString::number(queryOld.value(0).toInt()));
      replaceLine.append(", "+queryOld.value(1).toString());
      for(int y=0;y<(oldColumn < ui->columns->value() ? oldColumn : ui->columns->value());y++)
        {
          replaceLine.append(", "+QString::number(queryOld.value(y+2).toFloat()));
        }
      replaceLine.append(")");
      queryNew.exec(replaceLine);
    }
}
```

Then the header file is updated, and here is where I thought that the tableview will be redrawn:

```
void ImportProcess::updateHeadingTable()
{
  QSqlQuery query;
  query.exec("delete from C"+QString::number(markTime.toSecsSinceEpoch())+"T");
  QString description= ui->Week->isChecked() == true ? "Week" : "Size";
  query.exec("insert into C"+QString::number(markTime.toSecsSinceEpoch())+"T (id, description) values (101, '"+description+"')");
  for(int x=0;x<ui->columns->value();x++)
    {
      query.exec("update C"+QString::number(markTime.toSecsSinceEpoch())+"T set col"+QString::number(x)+" = '30'");
    }
  header->select();
  ui->heading->reset();

}
```

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: It is a pretty big program. I can make a sample if needed

Comment: @Dan3460, You need to edit your question and add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). . .

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So that you can improve your questions you should read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok, i will post excerpts of the code

Comment: Keep in mind that the code you post must reproduce the error and be complete in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot about some protected methods:

```
void QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertColumns(const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last);
void QAbstractItemModel::beginRemoveColumns(const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last);
void QAbstractItemModel::endInsertColumns();
void QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveColumns();
```

Every time the number of column about to be change you should call first or second method. After change you should call third or fours method.

You can read about these methods in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertColumns).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have read about those signals but all of them have this note on them: Note: This is a private signal. It can be used in signal connections but cannot be emitted by the user. So it seems to me that those commands are used when you are working on the model itself and not on the underling data

Comment: @Dan3460 sorry for my mistake, look on my edited answer.

Comment: I have solved the problem temporarily by using a fixed number of columns and controlling the hide and un-hide of columns. I would like to solve this to been able to add or take away columns on the fly. The problem is when i try to use those functions, the program does not compile because this are protected functions.

Comment: @Dan3460 you should subclass `QSqlTableModel` and use these methods from subclassed model.